# Is it better to use AUTOCOMMIT = 0

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-commit

Is it better to use (for perfomance tuning) `AUTOCOMMIT = 0` before bulk inserts of data in MySQL, if the insert query looks like

`INSERT INTO SomeTable (column1, column2) VALUES (val1,val2),(val3,val4),...` ?

Answer (score 7):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html), `AUTOCOMMIT` should be turned off in InnoDB.

> When importing data into InnoDB, turn off autocommit mode, because it performs a log flush to disk for every insert.
>
> When doing bulk inserts into tables with auto-increment columns, set [`innodb_autoinc_lock_mode`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoinc_lock_mode) to 2 instead of the default value 1

Comment: Every bulk INSERT in my case inserts 40000 values. So after how many inserts it is better to do `COMMIT` query?

Comment: After the entire `INSERT` is completed.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to commit more than once before the end of it. Like if your system is not stable enough and you fear it may crash or anything alike then you may commit as you see fit to protect your self from messing up the entire bulk

Comment: FreshPrinceOfSO, @Prix, I have 15 machines (Amazon AWS EC2 instances) which write continuosly to the high-memory MySQL server (Amazon RDS instance). Every machine write hundreds of million of rows. I think it is better in this case to make intermediate COMMITs?

Comment: `Every machine write hundreds of million of rows` per second ? per minute ? what is your benchmark, decide that after you know how many records you can insert within a range of time.

Answer (score 4):

You have a trade-off you need to be aware of.

Granted, it is true that a log flush happens with each `INSERT` involved with autocommit=1. Nevertheless, are there any consequences of setting autocommit=0 ?

Think about [**the redo logs (ib_logfile0,ib_logfile1) and the undo tablespace (inside ibdata1)**](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing). Change information must be stored somewhere in case the INSERTs need to be rolled back or recovery is initiated after a crash.

Either way, there will be some disk I/O to contend with.

Additionally, consider [**innodb_log_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size)

- Smaller Log Buffer means more frequent flushes
- Bigger Log Buffer means you will save on disk I/O flushes but commits will hang longer
- In most cases, the default values should suffice

These are facts. Let the buyer beware.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off definitely helps if [`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) is set to 1.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1
(col1 INT, col2 VARCHAR(20), col3 INT, KEY idx_tab1_col1(col1))ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Test:

- Hardware: MAC with SSD.
- Insert 1 million records with autocommit turned OFF.
- Insert 1 million records with autocommit turned ON.

Results:

- Autocommit ON: 4+ minutes;
- Autocommit OFF: 30 seconds.

Comment: How many rows in each batch?

Answer (score 1):

If you are inserting 40K rows per `INSERT` statement, then commit it right away.  (This implies, for simplicity, having `autocommit=ON`.)

If instead, you have thousands of such bulk inserts and use `autocommit=OFF` or `BEGIN`, then you are building up a huge transaction.  This will overflow the logs (needed to undo the inserts in case of a crash).  InnoDB can handle the overflow, but it slows things down.

On the other hand, if you need the entire load to be 'atomic', then go ahead and make it one big transaction.

Similarly, `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2` and `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2` help with speed (at the expense of safety).  However, this is 'global', thereby impacting all connections.

If your task is to load a bunch of data, especially if this is an initial load, then you could take this approach:  Run the task with the fastest settings; in the unlikely event of a crash, drop the tables and start over.

If you are loading into a Master, then presenting smaller chunks to the Slaves helps with the replication flow (especially in Statement Based Replication).