# How does autocommit=off affects bulk inserts performance in mysql using innodb?

Tags: mysql, transaction

I know that turning off autocommit can improve bulk insert performance a lot according to:

[Is it better to use AUTOCOMMIT = 0](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42704/is-it-better-to-use-autocommit-0)

And I have made experiments to confirm that conclusion. But what I want to know is, why turning off autocommit can improve bulk inserts? And what happens internally in inno db when a transaction is commited?

Comment: What do you mean with bulk insert, is it one insert that inserts many rows, or several inserts?

Comment: I added an Answer to the Question you linked to.

Answer (score 2):

**There are 3 ways to do transactions.**  *All* 3 of the following involve transactions.

```
SET autocommit = ON;

INSERT ... VALUES (1,2), (2,3), ...;  -- This is one transaction
another INSERT/UPDATE/etc;  -- This is another transaction
```

Or...

```
SET autocommit = OFF;

INSERT ... VALUES (1,2), (2,3), ...;
another INSERT/UPDATE/etc;  
COMMIT;     -- Terminate the ONE transaction (with 2 statements)
```

Or

```
BEGIN;   -- aka START TRANSACTION;
INSERT ... VALUES (1,2), (2,3), ...;
another INSERT/UPDATE/etc;
COMMIT;     -- Terminate the ONE transaction (with 2 statements)
```

If you are doing a bulk `INSERT`, you *probably* want it to be a transaction unto itself, since you have already combined a lot of 1-row inserts into a "bulk" insert.

**Speed:**

- A transaction has some overhead.
- A statement has some overhead.

Therefore:

- Fastest:  Bulk `INSERT` (one statement in one transaction)
- Medium:  A bunch of 1-row `INSERT` statements between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` is
- Slowest:  1-row `INSERTs`, each one being a separate transaction.

**Tip:**  Don't use `autocommit=0` because you might forget to issue the `COMMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

If autocommit is turned off, you can always do a `ROLLBACK` to get back to the state the database was in before you started doing something.
`COMMIT` makes sure all changes to the database are written permanently, doing this for every `INSERT` takes more time than doing this for *a  lot of* `INSERT`s, because not only the records needs to be inserted, also the indexes needs to be updated. Doing this last piece for *a lot of records* is more efficient than doing this for 1 record at a time.